# Integrating SQL Reporting Service into a C# WebAPI app

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

I want to integrate SQL Reporting Service into my C# WebAPI app. I already read

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964126%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964126(v=sql.90).aspx

but either I overlooked the relevant parts, or my questions are not answered there.

So, for a start: I have already created a rdl file. When my report API is called, I want to preprocess data, put it into the sql server, create a PDF report, store it on IIS, destroy all copies that may be left on the report server, delete the data from the sql server and be done.

How can I do this with C# WebAPI and SQL Report Server, or is it impossible?

Especially: Is there a library with which I can work with the Report Server via SOAP, or will I have to build the SOAP calls by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need all of the "enterprisey" features of a full blown reporting serverices installation you could include a [LocalReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.aspx) in your web api project.  You can instantiate it from code, bind to objects, get the bytes of your PDF and send them back through your web api service.  It's actually my preferred way of doing reporting, it's part of the app, uses the apps permision model instead of SSRS, uses the apps deployment model instead of SSRS.  The biggest thing for me has been that the export formats are a little more limited PDF, Excel and Word last time I used it.

```
LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
report.ReportPath = "SomePath";
report.DataSources.Clear();
report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SomeDataSourceName", 
        SomeCollectionObject));
report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SomeOtherDataSourceName", 
            SomeOtherCollectionObject));
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string mimeType, encoding, filenameExtension;
byte[] array = report.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

Comment: That's great. I came back to SO to look for advice on how to bring that report server up and running, and found that I don't need it. :)

Comment: Reporting services offers a lot, it's just that most of the time I don't need any of it :)

Comment: Are you returning the byte array from your controller method?  Is this a WebAPI controller?  Curious what you are using for your media type in the response header.